# .htaccess redirection from multiple directories to a single page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a single blog.php page that should get redirected from all these requests:

**www.site.com/blog**     #*goes to blog.php*

**www.site.com/blog/id-of-an-entry**    *#goes to blog.php?id=id-of-an-entry*

Also internationalised versions such for french:

**www.site.com/fr/blog**            *# to   blog.php?lang=fr

**www.site.com/fr/blog/id-of-entry***   *#to            blog.php?lang=fr&id=id-of-entry*

What would be the more eficient and effective cond/rules for .htaccess? I've made many attemps but end walking in circles or with to many specialised rules :-) Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/?$ /blog.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /blog.php [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/([^/]+)/?$ /blog.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/blog/?$ /blog.php?lang=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Let me add a related question, while testing I am on http://localhost/site/blog.php. What would you do to have it working here too? (localhost/site/blog/the-id redirecting to localhost/site/blog.php?id?the-id)

Comment: @Juan: Just have a rule like this: `RewriteRule ^(site/blog)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L,NC,QSA]` for that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not using this regulary so there can be better way but this could help you. Rules works like this. In `()` are your variables which corresponds to what you want to match. Than you can refer to them by `$1` and so on. For example `news/local` would redirect them to file `news-local.php` you can use the same system to match you get variables.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ $1-$2.php
```